# Flutter playing audio in android taking too much time in compare to iOS

Tags: android, flutter, dart

For testing purpose I'm developing one of the app where in the app I'm playing live streaming audio url.

To play audio I'm tried with both package.

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer and https://pub.dev/packages/fluttery_audio

In both package, iOS working well but in android device with version 8 and 9. Taking too much time.

If there is problem in the package or something need to settings for android? Anybody has faced same issue ?

> - ps: For code I'm simply using packer code when I just changed with below url.

```
const kUrl1 = 'http://uk3.internet-radio.com:8405/live';
const kUrl2 = 'http://uk6.internet-radio.com:8179/;stream';
const kUrl3 = 'http://us5.internet-radio.com:8022/;stream';
```

Comment: That should be posted issue on the packages repositories, instead of here.

Comment: Are you using iPhone simulator or physical device?

Comment: I have tried in both device as well as simulator. Actually issue is only with android device.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this issue and tried many ways, what solved my issue I switching the package to [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio). Now it's working perfectly on both platforms.